# rank, last_value(), first_value, what to use? | BigQuery | SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following columns in Bigquery: Value1, Value2 a startdate and a enddate. See the picture below.

- I want to add the column datewanted with the max date of value2. But the max date before value 2 changes.
- I want to remove the red lines (with keeprow = FALSE)

I used last_value or rank() but I can't seem to get the correct output. Mainly because last_value picks the last date from value2 and not the last_value before value2 changes.

[image]

Comment: What's the logic for "datewanted"? The latest entry in enddate full stop, or the latest for that value2?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt the latest for that value2. So not the latest overall but the latest before value2 changes to another value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want the "first" enddate after Val2 changes.

I had to recreate your tables with similar columns, so you can test with your real data.
So I guess this query solves your problem:

```
WITH
data
AS (
  SELECT 'abc' as Value1, 123 as Value2, 1 as start_time, 2 as end_time union all
  SELECT 'abc' as Value1, 123 as Value2, 2 as start_time, 3 as end_time union all
  SELECT 'abc' as Value1, 1234 as Value2, 3 as start_time, 4 as end_time union all
  SELECT 'abc' as Value1, 123 as Value2, 4 as start_time, 5 as end_time union all
  SELECT 'abc' as Value1, 1234 as Value2, 5 as start_time, 6 as end_time union all
  SELECT 'abc' as Value1, 1234 as Value2, 6 as start_time, 7 as end_time union all
  SELECT 'abc' as Value1, 123 as Value2, 7 as start_time, 8 as end_time union all
  SELECT 'abc' as Value1, 123 as Value2, 8 as start_time, 9 as end_time union all
  SELECT 'abc' as Value1, 123 as Value2, 9 as start_time, 10 as end_time union all
  SELECT 'abc' as Value1, 123 as Value2, 10 as start_time, 11 as end_time union all
  SELECT 'abc' as Value1, 1234 as Value2, 11 as start_time, 12 as end_time union all
  SELECT 'abc' as Value1, 1234 as Value2, 12 as start_time, 13 as end_time union all
  SELECT 'abc' as Value1, 123 as Value2, 13 as start_time, 14 as end_time union all
  SELECT 'abc' as Value1, 123 as Value2, 14 as start_time, 15 as end_time
),
delta
AS (
  select *, 
    case when Value2 != lag(Value2) over (partition by Value1 order by start_time) then 1 else 0 end as value_changed
  from data
),
changes
AS (
  select Value1, Value2, start_time, end_time, sum(value_changed) over (partition by Value1 order by start_time) as change_index
  from delta
)
select Value1, Value2, change_index, min(start_time) as start_time, max(end_time) as end_time
from changes
group by Value1, Value2, change_index
```